# change the output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sorry I am new to sql world could this statement be checkin time  different with checkout time and remove checkinorout from the statement as you well see :

```
SELECT  
  USERINFO.Badgenumber AS USERID, 
  CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME AS Checkin, 
  CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME AS Checkout, 
  Machines.MachineAlias, 
  CHECKINOUT.checkinorout
FROM CHECKINOUT 
  INNER JOIN USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID 
  INNER JOIN Machines ON CHECKINOUT.SENSORID = Machines.MachineNumber
WHERE (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME > '2014-09-25 00:00:00.000') 
order by checkin
```

Output:

```
  USERID    Checkin              Checkout               Machines checkinorout
    32  2014-09-25 09:12:57.000 2014-09-25 09:12:57.000 HQ       Checkin   
    32  2014-09-25 12:58:51.000 2014-09-25 12:58:51.000 HQ       CheckOut  
    32  2014-09-26 18:03:33.000 2014-09-26 18:03:33.000 HQ       Checkin    
    32  2014-09-26 22:03:11.000 2014-09-26 22:03:11.000 HQ       CheckOut   
    32  2014-09-27 12:57:55.000 2014-09-27 12:57:55.000 HQ       Checkin    
    32  2014-09-27 17:01:32.000 2014-09-27 17:01:32.000 HQ       CheckOut   
    32  2014-09-28 13:05:03.000 2014-09-28 13:05:03.000 HQ       Checkin    
    32  2014-09-28 17:35:29.000 2014-09-28 17:35:29.000 HQ       CheckOut  
    32  2014-09-29 09:18:12.000 2014-09-29 09:18:12.000 HQ       Checkin    
    32  2014-09-29 18:10:43.000 2014-09-29 18:10:43.000 HQ       CheckOut   
    32  2014-09-30 09:12:13.000 2014-09-30 09:12:13.000 HQ       Checkin
```

I need the output   be like this

```
USERID  Checkin                 Checkout                 Machines 
    32  2014-09-25 09:12:57.000 2014-09-25 12:58:51.000  HQ         
    32  2014-09-26 18:03:33.000 2014-09-26 22:03:11.000  HQ         
    32  2014-09-27 12:57:55.000 2014-09-27 17:01:32.000  HQ
    32  2014-09-28 13:05:03.000 2014-09-28 17:35:29.000  HQ          
    32  2014-09-29 09:18:12.000 2014-09-29 18:10:43.000  HQ
```

Thanks MR @sgeddes but when i edit your statement  to have a result

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by userid, checkinorout order by CHECKTIME) rn
  from CHECKINOUT
  )
select userid, 
    max(case when checkinorout = 'checkin' then CHECKTIME end) checkin, 
    max(case when checkinorout = 'checkout' then CHECKTIME end) checkout

from cte where USERID=15 and  CHECKTIME between '2014-9-21 00:00:00.000' and '2014-10-25 00:00:00.000'
group by userid , rn 


userid checkin  checkout 
15  NULL    2014-09-21 18:50:24.000
15  NULL    2014-09-22 18:06:15.000
15  NULL    2014-09-23 18:01:30.000
15  NULL    2014-09-24 16:52:36.000
15  NULL    2014-09-25 12:58:51.000
15  NULL    2014-09-26 22:03:11.000
15  NULL    2014-09-27 17:01:32.000
15  NULL    2014-09-28 17:35:29.000
15  NULL    2014-09-29 18:10:43.000
15  NULL    2014-09-30 18:11:19.000
15  NULL    2014-10-01 17:52:49.000
15  NULL    2014-10-12 20:13:10.000
15  2014-09-21 10:17:24.000 2014-10-13 22:13:11.000
15  2014-09-22 09:18:29.000 2014-10-14 21:49:28.000
15  2014-09-23 09:10:15.000 2014-10-15 10:14:09.000
15  2014-09-24 09:43:27.000 2014-10-16 17:55:06.000
15  2014-09-25 09:12:57.000 2014-10-17 23:17:00.000
15  2014-09-26 18:03:33.000 2014-10-20 12:38:22.000
15  2014-09-27 12:57:55.000 2014-10-21 07:31:39.000
15  2014-09-28 13:05:03.000 2014-10-22 05:51:47.000
15  2014-09-29 09:18:12.000 2014-10-24 11:26:06.000
15  2014-09-30 09:12:13.000 NULL
15  2014-10-01 10:16:59.000 NULL
15  2014-10-02 10:13:52.000 NULL
15  2014-10-03 00:59:18.000 NULL
15  2014-10-11 22:07:06.000 NULL
15  2014-10-12 09:58:34.000 NULL
15  2014-10-13 05:09:34.000 NULL
15  2014-10-14 11:42:58.000 NULL
15  2014-10-15 04:48:27.000 NULL
15  2014-10-15 15:49:06.000 NULL
15  2014-10-16 09:14:21.000 NULL
15  2014-10-16 21:14:18.000 NULL
15  2014-10-17 00:59:57.000 NULL
15  2014-10-18 17:42:26.000 NULL
15  2014-10-20 01:22:01.000 NULL
15  2014-10-21 01:24:30.000 NULL
15  2014-10-22 00:10:34.000 NULL
15  2014-10-23 20:01:02.000 NULL
15  2014-10-24 01:08:51.000 NULL
```

and i need it to be

```
userid checkin              checkout
15  2014-09-21 10:17:24.000 2014-09-21 18:50:24.000
15  2014-09-22 09:18:29.000 2014-09-22 18:06:15.000
15  2014-09-23 09:10:15.000 2014-09-23 18:01:30.000
15  2014-09-24 09:43:27.000 2014-09-24 16:52:36.000
15  2014-09-25 09:12:57.000 2014-09-25 12:58:51.000
15  2014-09-26 18:03:33.000 2014-09-26 22:03:11.000
15  2014-09-27 12:57:55.000 2014-09-27 17:01:32.000
```

Thanks Mr @slavoo

what i have when i try ....

```
    SELECT  
  u.Badgenumber AS USERID, 
  c.CHECKTIME AS Checkout, 
  checkingOut.time AS Checkin, 
  m.MachineAlias
FROM CHECKINOUT c
  INNER JOIN USERINFO u ON c.USERID = u.USERID 
  INNER JOIN Machines m ON c.SENSORID = m.MachineNumber
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT top 1 c2.CHECKTIME as time FROM CHECKINOUT c2 
  WHERE c2.checkinorout = 'Checkout' 
  AND c.USERID = c2.USERID
  AND c.SENSORID = c2.SENSORID
  AND c.CHECKTIME < c2.CHECKTIME
  order by c2.CHECKTIME asc
 ) as checkingOut
WHERE  (c.CHECKTIME between  '2014-10-19 00:00:00.000' and '2014-10-27 00:00:00.000' ) 
    and u.Badgenumber=660  
  AND c.checkinorout = 'Checkin' 
  AND checkingOut.time is not null
order by checkingOut.time
```

The output:

```
   USERID   Checkout             Checkin                MachineAlias
    660 2014-10-19 01:56:47.000 2014-10-19 17:27:41.000 Branch4 
    660 2014-10-20 02:00:14.000 2014-10-20 17:39:35.000 Branch4 
    660 2014-10-21 01:55:49.000 2014-10-21 16:57:22.000 Branch4 
    660 2014-10-22 01:59:23.000 2014-10-25 16:48:29.000 Branch4 
    660 2014-10-23 16:59:34.000 2014-10-25 16:48:29.000 Branch4 
    660 2014-10-24 16:58:36.000 2014-10-25 16:48:29.000 Branch4 
    660 2014-10-25 01:56:47.000 2014-10-25 16:48:29.000 Branch4
```

and i need it to be

```
 USERID   Checkout               Checkin                MachineAlias
    660 2014-10-20 02:00:14.000 2014-10-19 17:27:41.000 Branch4 
    660 2014-10-21 01:55:49.000 2014-10-20 17:39:35.000 Branch4 
    660 2014-10-22 01:59:23.000 2014-10-21 16:57:22.000 Branch4 
    660 Null                    2014-10-23 16:59:34.000 Branch4
    660 2014-10-25 01:56:47.000 2014-10-24 16:58:36.000 Branch4 
    660 2014-10-26 00:55:35.000 2014-10-25 16:48:29.000 Branch4
```

and this is the table i read from it

```
    select USERID ,CHECKTIME,checkinorout from CHECKINOUT where USERID=80 and CHECKTIME between  '2014-10-19 00:00:00.000' and '2014-10-27 00:00:00.000'
order by CHECKTIME
```

and this is the full transaction for this user

```
80  2014-10-19 01:56:47.000 Checkin   
80  2014-10-19 17:27:41.000 CheckOut  
80  2014-10-20 02:00:14.000 Checkin   
80  2014-10-20 17:39:35.000 CheckOut  
80  2014-10-21 01:55:49.000 Checkin   
80  2014-10-21 16:57:22.000 CheckOut  
80  2014-10-22 01:59:23.000 Checkin   
80  2014-10-23 16:59:34.000 Checkin   
80  2014-10-24 16:58:36.000 Checkin   
80  2014-10-25 01:56:47.000 Checkin   
80  2014-10-25 16:48:29.000 CheckOut  
80  2014-10-26 00:55:35.000 Checkin
```

***for your note i have script its update the check in or out in checkinorout column***

to know this report be finger print check in and check out report 
and if he found no check in leave  it Null and if he found the check out null leave it null ( this employ have shift check in 5:00:00 pm and check out 2:00:00 am ) ; .

Comment: Try my answer once. It is difficult to give you perfect answer without seeing full data based on your sample data sgeddes gave you an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  
  u.Badgenumber AS USERID, 
  c.CHECKTIME AS Checkin, 
  checkingOut.time AS Checkout, 
  m.MachineAlias
FROM CHECKINOUT c
  INNER JOIN users u ON c.USERID = u.USERID 
  INNER JOIN Machines m ON c.SENSORID = m.MachineNumber
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT top 1 c2.CHECKTIME as time FROM CHECKINOUT c2 
  WHERE c2.checkinorout = 'Checkout' 
  AND c.USERID = c2.USERID
  AND c.SENSORID = c2.SENSORID
  AND c.CHECKTIME < c2.CHECKTIME
  AND CAST(c.CHECKTIME as DATE) = CAST(c2.CHECKTIME as DATE)
  order by c2.CHECKTIME asc
 ) as checkingOut
WHERE (c.CHECKTIME > '2014-09-25 00:00:00.000') 
  AND c.checkinorout = 'Checkin' 
order by checkin
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43ab5/4)

[SQL Fiddle after update](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/942d73/1)

Or this:

```
SELECT  
  u.Badgenumber AS USERID, 
  c.CHECKTIME AS Checkin, 
  checkingOut.time AS Checkout, 
  Machines.MachineAlias
FROM CHECKINOUT c
  INNER JOIN users u ON c.USERID = u.USERID 
  INNER JOIN Machines ON c.SENSORID = Machines.MachineNumber
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT top 1 c2.CHECKTIME as time FROM CHECKINOUT c2 
  WHERE c2.checkinorout = 'Checkout' 
  AND c.USERID = c2.USERID
  AND c.SENSORID = c2.SENSORID
  AND c.CHECKTIME < c2.CHECKTIME
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT c3                       
                  WHERE c3.checkinorout = 'Checkin'
                  AND c3.USERID = c2.USERID
                  AND c3.SENSORID = c2.SENSORID
                  AND c3.CHECKTIME > c.CHECKTIME
                  AND c3.CHECKTIME < c2.CHECKTIME)
  order by c2.CHECKTIME asc
 ) as checkingOut
WHERE (c.CHECKTIME > '2014-09-25 00:00:00.000') 
  AND c.checkinorout = 'Checkin'       
order by checkin
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/942d73/8)

Comment: @NewUser I don't see this line `AND c.checkinorout = 'Checkin'` in your query.

Comment: sorry i forget to run the script wish update the column checkinorout i think its my be the problem in it its update the column wrong .

Comment: the last script is perfect but the problem in update check in or out script  in checkinorout column , can i open anew question to show it and answer it :)

Comment: I frogot in EXIST select to add these two rows `AND c.USERID = c2.USERID` and `AND c.SENSORID = c2.SENSORID`. Now it is fixed.

Comment: nothing its the same but i writ anew quetion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574176/edit-this-script

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to establish a grouping between your checkins and checkouts.  Then you need to pivot your results -- you can use `MAX` with `CASE` to do that:

Here's a simplified version using a common table expression:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by userid, checkinorout order by checkin) rn
  from results
  )
select userid, 
    max(case when checkinorout = 'checkin' then checkin end) checkin, 
    max(case when checkinorout = 'checkout' then checkout end) checkout, 
    machines
from cte
group by userid, machines, rn
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e305/3)

---

Edit, given your comments, can you not just use a `HAVING` clause to remove the `NULL` records?

```
having max(case when checkinorout = 'checkin' then checkin end) is not null
  and  max(case when checkinorout = 'checkout' then checkout end) is not null
```

- [Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e305/5)